# mysql unique statement

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table like so

```
ID     |   date  |    CODE 

1        01-02-13     VDOT
2        03-02-13     CMAX
3        05-02-13     VDOT
1        05-02-13     CMAX
1        09-02-13     VDOT
```

My SQL query is as follows

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name ;
```

Which is obviously showing all the results but I need to only show one instance of each code where the date is most recent so my result needs to look like this

```
1        09-02-13     VDOT
1        05-02-13     CMAX
```

Can anyone tell me how how to only get one result for each code (the most recent entry by date)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name 
GROUP BY CODE
ORDER BY date DESC
```

This will ORDER after it groups. hence gives out ORDERS within the grouped-results.

.

But now try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY date DESC) tx2 
GROUP BY CODE
```

This will ensure correct date ORDER before GROUP.

Comment: Note that this will only work in MySQL, but will be invalid SQL in all other DBMS or  if MySQL has been configured with "strict_group_by"

Comment: this is simple but this will not give you correct values always, see here [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: @JW: What you mentioned only becomes an issue when fields are mentioned in the `SELECT`. But here `*` is mentioned and hence it will work.

Comment: @JW: Second thing mentioned on that page is about using functions like `FLOOR`, `COUNT` etc. They are also not used in this case here.

Comment: @RaheelHasan see this, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73512b/1 your query returns different result. `TableName` and `TableName2` has the same number of records an calue but the values are interchange.

Comment: @BarryConnolly are you sure with this?

Comment: @JW: check updated version above now. It works. Your concerns about incorrect Date Order was right, but you had no idea why! and hence you were pointing to wrong issue.

Comment: let me ask you, do you have any experience on handling large databases? According to the documentation, when using `GROUP BY` by not specifying non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause will not guarantee to return the same values on the non aggregated columns. Perhaps your query will work since you have only tested for  5 records. Anyway your answer was chosen as the right answer `:)`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  CODE, MAX(date) max_date
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY CODE
        ) b ON  a.Code = b.Code AND
                a.date = b.max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
TABLE AS A
JOIN
(
SELECT D.CODE, MAX(D.DATE) AS DATE FROM TABLE AS D
GROUP BY D.CODE
) AS E
WHERE 
A.CODE =  E.CODE
AND A.DATE = E.DATE
```